# How can I read int values from json file in Java?

Tags: arrays, json, type-conversion

I want to take "ids" and assign it to an arraylist. config.json file is here:

```
{

  "users":[
  {"user id":1,"user name":"A","user type":"bot1", "ids": [1 ,2]},
  {"user id":2,"user name":"B","user type":"bot2","ids": [1 ,2]},
  {"user id":3,"user name":"C","user type":"bot3","ids": [2 ,3]}
  ]
}
```

To read this json file I have tried this:

```
JSONArray jsonArrayForUsers = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("users");
            
            for (int i=0; i<jsonArrayForUsers.size(); i++) { 
                JSONObject obj2 = (JSONObject) jsonArrayForUsers.get(i); 
                long userId = (long) obj2.get("user id"); 
                String userName = (String) obj2.get("user name");
                String userType = (String) obj2.get("user type");
                JSONArray jsonDatasetIds = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("ids");
                 List <Integer> list =  Arrays.asList(jsonDatasetIds);// Trying to covert JSONArray into an array but error occurs
 
//Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<JSONArray> to List<Integer>
                
                
                users.add(new User((int)userId, userName, userType,list));
            }
```

I could read "user id", "user name" , "user type" correctly. But I don't know how to read -"ids": [1 ,2]- part and create an arraylist from it.

Edit:
Problem solved after I've changed

```
               //It should've been 'obj2.get()'
               JSONArray  jsonDatasetIds = (JSONArray) obj2.get("ids");

               
               for(int a = 0; i<jsonDatasetIds.size();i++){
                   
                   list.add((int)jsonDatasetIds.get(a));
               }
               users.add(new User((int)userId, userName, userType,list));
```

But now I can not add values from 'jsonDatasetIds' to 'list'.
In other words I can not take values from JSONArray.

Comment: In the JSON example you posted the key is "ids" while in the java part you are reading a key "dataset ids". Try reading jsonObject.get("ids"). Also you can not convert a JSONArray into a List<Integer> that way, All you are doing calling Arrays.asList is wrapping the object JSONArray into a new List. Which library are you using to parse and read the JSON?

Comment: I am using this "org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser"
I also have corrected "ids" part  @DanielCamarda

Comment: Not sure about that library but JSONArray is most probably some sort of iterable, if that's the case you can loop through the elements directly.

Comment: Actually with some googling here is an article which shows how to iterate a JSONArray with json-simple https://mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/
My advice is to use a more complete library like Jackson or Gson, which also supports direct marshalling and unmarshalling of custom objects, so you can directliy map a java bean to a JSON entity.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to improve the code, let's start by reformulating the problem: You need to go from a JSON string to a model object with all the attributes mapped.

There are good libraries for doing just this, like [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) and [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson), but it can also be done with [json-simple 1.1.1](https://code.google.com/archive/p/json-simple/) as you are doing.

Assuming your model object looks like this:

```java
public class User {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private List<Integer> ids;

    // and constructor + getters + setters
}
```

And starting from the JSON you provided:

```json
{
  "users":[
    {"user id":1, "user name":"A", "user type":"bot1", "ids":[1, 2]},
    {"user id":2, "user name":"B", "user type":"bot2", "ids":[1, 2]},
    {"user id":3, "user name":"C", "user type":"bot3", "ids":[2, 3]}
  ]
}
```

We can make a first attempt that looks like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String json =
            "{  \"users\":[" +
            "  {\"user id\":1,\"user name\":\"A\",\"user type\":\"bot1\", \"ids\": [1 ,2]}," +
            "  {\"user id\":2,\"user name\":\"B\",\"user type\":\"bot2\",\"ids\": [1 ,2]}," +
            "  {\"user id\":3,\"user name\":\"C\",\"user type\":\"bot3\",\"ids\": [2 ,3]}" +
            "  ]" +
            "}";
            
    List<User> result = new ArrayList<>();

    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject root = (JSONObject) parser.parse(json);
    List<JSONObject> users = (List<JSONObject>) root.get("users");

    for (JSONObject user: users) {
        List<Integer> userIds = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Long id : (List<Long>) user.get("ids")) {
            userIds.add(id.intValue());
        }

        result.add(new User(((Long)user.get("user id")).intValue(), (String) user.get("user name"), (String) user.get("user type"), userIds));
    }

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

As you can see a JSONArray can be directly casted to a List, and if we look at the signature of JSONArray class we can understand why:

```java
public class JSONArray extends ArrayList implements List, JSONAware, JSONStreamAware
```

JSONArray is actually extending ArrayList so you do not need to create a new one and that is why the line `List<JSONObject> users = (List<JSONObject>) root.get("users");` works.

Now that you have a list its possible to iterate over the elements with the usual foreach loop `for (JSONObject user: users) {...}` and process each element.

For the internal "ids" we could do the same thing but from your code it seems the ids must be integers and json-simple returns `Long` objects, so we need to convert them and that is why the second loop is there (if the model object accepted a `List<Long>` it would not be needed).

A different way for doing the same thing is with java 8 streams, specifying the different steps you need to convert the source object into the destination one:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String json =
            "{  \"users\":[" +
            "  {\"user id\":1,\"user name\":\"A\",\"user type\":\"bot1\", \"ids\": [1 ,2]}," +
            "  {\"user id\":2,\"user name\":\"B\",\"user type\":\"bot2\",\"ids\": [1 ,2]}," +
            "  {\"user id\":3,\"user name\":\"C\",\"user type\":\"bot3\",\"ids\": [2 ,3]}" +
            "  ]" +
            "}";
    
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject root = (JSONObject) parser.parse(json);
    
    List<User> result = ((List<JSONObject>)root.get("users"))
            .stream()
            .map(user -> new User(
                ((Long)user.get("user id")).intValue(),
                (String) user.get("user name"),
                (String) user.get("user type"),
                ((List<Long>) user.get("ids"))
                        .stream()
                        .map(Long::intValue)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());


    System.out.println(result);
}
```

In my opinion the [stream api](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams.html) is more clear in situations when you need to go step by step transforming a list of objects from one type to another, in this example it does not makes much of a difference but in more complex situations with many intermediate steps it can be a really useful tool.